# Apache CXF - bind interceptor to service method

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, interceptor, ws-security

I'm trying to figure out how to encrypt different methods in different ways. For example I've got a test-service with two methods. I want one of these methods accessible without authentication, encryption or anything. Just anyone shall be able to use it. The second method on the other hand should have a signated and an encrypted body and only those clients known to the server shall be able to access that second method.
My Problem now is that I can do either one these. I can encrypt the soap-messages of all methods or of none.
So what I need is something that would probably look pretty much like this:

```
<bean id="Method_Interceptor" class="${methodInterceptorClass}">
    <constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="methodName"/> 
        <ref bean="TimestampSignEncrypt_Request"/>
        <ref bean="TimestampSignEncrypt_Response"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="TimestampSignEncrypt_Request" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <!-- Use this action order for local clients -->
            <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature Encrypt"/>
            <!-- Use this action spec for WCF clients
            <entry key="action" value="Signature Encrypt Timestamp"/>
            -->
            <entry key="signaturePropFile"
                   value="de/narz/apacheCXFTest/helloWorld/keyManagement/config/fiverx.link.trust.properties"/>
            <entry key="decryptionPropFile"
                   value="de/narz/apacheCXFTest/helloWorld/keyManagement/config/fiverx.link.properties"/>
            <entry key="passwordCallbackClass"
                   value="de.narz.apacheCXFTest.helloWorld.passwordHandling.PasswordCallbackHandler"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="TimestampSignEncrypt_Response" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
    ...
```

is it possible to do it? I did not find anything after hours of research...

Comment: You can split it by two different service with different wsdl. I think it easiest way.

Comment: that is unfortunately not an option. In production we would also need to have 2 clients then.